# How do I access the web server on my desktop from my laptop?

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server, localhost

I'm running Apache on my stationary and I would like to access a website through my laptop.
This is some of the Apache config:

```
NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
    ServerName mysite.com
    DocumentRoot I:/wamp/www/mysite/
</VirtualHost>

ServerName localhost:80

<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride all
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>
```

On my laptop I've added the following to the `HOSTS` file:

```
10.0.0.3   mysite.com
```

But accessing the page through mysite.com is not very successfull. If I enter the IP address directly, I only get a `Forbidden` message.

What do I need to do in order to get this to work?

**Update**

I'm runing WAMPSERVER 2.1 (Apache 2.2.17)
Apache is up and running
I can ping 10.0.0.3 from laptop
I'm not able to ping http://mysite.com from laptop
IE gives me a `403 Forbidden` -> `The website declined to show this webpage`

The only log that get's entries when trying to access the website from my laptop, is access.log.

**access.log**
10.0.0.4 - - [13/Jun/2011:10:14:04 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 202

**apache_error.log**
[Mon Jun 13 10:08:16 2011] [error] VirtualHost localhost:0 -- mixing * ports and non-* ports with a NameVirtualHost address is not supported, proceeding with undefined results

**UPDATE 2**
My apache config has the following entry:

```
AllowOverride all
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1
```

Could it be that this `Allow from` is stopping other computers accessing the page?

Comment: Post the relevant entries from your error log. If you're getting a 'Forbidden' message the error log will have more details in. There are hundreds of reasons that error could be caused by.

Comment: Are there any firewalls in place? Is the Apache Webservice running? Can it be pinged? Try access it just from the webserver's IP rather than the hosts file, to start with.

Comment: I've added som info.

Comment: When you're asking a question like this, you need to think what it leaves behind for people who look at the site later - you should upvote answers that were helpful, and create an answer for anything else you do, rather than leaving comments inline.  Right now the original problem isn't included in the question, for example.

Comment: @crb, how is my original problem not included in the question? The headline states pretty clearly what the problem is. I upvote answers that are helpfull. So far, there is only one answer and it was not helpfull. It did not solve my problem. When time permits, I will add an answer to my own solution and mark is at solved.

Comment: You edited the question to invalidate the problem which I added the answer for.

Comment: @crb, I changed `localhost` to `127.0.0.1:80` because I forgot. The problem still remained the same until I found the solution myself.

Answer (score 1):

I discovered that the problem was in `Allow from` section.

I just had to add the IP addresses of the computers I wanted to get access.

```
AllowOverride all
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1
Allow from 10.0.0.1
Allow from 10.0.0.2
Allow from 10.0.0.3
```

Answer (score 0):

You at least should specify a port for your `VirtualHost` and `NameVirtualHost` directives. For example:

```
<VirtualHost localhost:80>
```

The [Apache docs on using name-based virtual hosts](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html) are thorough and worth a read.

Comment: I've done that (127.0.0.1:80), but it's not working. I've also tried using 10.0.0.3:80, but doing that, I'm not able to access the page from localhost either. I've read the docs.

Comment: Could `Allow from` be the source of my problem? See update.

Comment: Yup, that was it. By adding `Allow from 10.0.0.3` for my laptop and `Allow from 10.0.0.4` for my local computer, then it all worked :)